# .NET XmlSerializer (de)serializing derived type from a different namespace with schema compiler xsd.exe and wrong namespace binding

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xsd

I'm trying to use the [XML Schema Definition Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to generate CS code from the following schemas:

A.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="Bar">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="v" type="xs:double"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Base"/>
    <xs:element name="root" type="Base" />
</xs:schema>
```

B.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="v2" targetNamespace="v2" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import schemaLocation="A.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Derived">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Base">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="b" type="Bar"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I execute xsd.exe schema compiler like this:

xsd.exe A.xsd B.xsd /c

and get a B_A.cs file (a lot of code, feel free to regenerate yourself).

There's two unexpected pieces of behaviour.

Serialization:
If you serialize an instance of a Bar of type Derived:

```
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Base));
    Derived d = new Derived();
    d.b = new Bar();
    d.b.v = 12.123;
    serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, d);
```

you get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:q1="v2" xsi:type="q1:Derived">
  <q1:b>
    <q1:v>12.123</q1:v>
  </q1:b>
</root>
```

Which doesn't validate with B.xsd beceause the v element in b is namespace prefixed with q1.  Get rid of the prefix, it validates, as (I believe) is right.

Similarly, the other way around.  Take this instance document, which validates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:q1="v2" xsi:schemaLocation="v2 B.xsd" xsi:type="q1:Derived">
  <q1:b>
    <v>12.123</v>
  </q1:b>
</root>
```

Try to deserialize it with the generated code, like this:

```
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Base));
    Bar p = (Bar)serializer.Deserialize(new FileStream(@"..\..\test.xml", FileMode.Open));
    Console.Out.WriteLine(p.v);
```

You get 0.0 output, becaues v is default initialized.  Add the q1: prefix to the v element of the instance document, and it works, but is not valid.

Would anyone agree that the this is the fault of the XML Schema definition tool?  I don't believe it's generating proper serialization code, but it's hard to blame the tools.  If we add XmlElement attributes with Namespace="" to v, it works, but now I'm modifying the generated code, which is not desirable (the project I'm working generates the code as part of the build - we're not supposed to change it).

Any ideas how I could work around this?

Comment: Offhand, I would expect XSD to have a problem with this since the A schema is not in a namespace. I would recommend starting from the code you want, and producing a schema from that, assuming that you require a schema.

Comment: I've done a lot with serialization, and I have always found the xml schema stuff to be way too complicated.  Do you have a specific requirement to do it this way, or would you be open to other methods?

Comment: The c# code generation is just one side - we do the same for an ANSI C++ application and generate it's serialization routines using Codesynthesis XSD (great tool, doesn't have this problem).  I'd like to switch to something better than XML(Goggle protocol buffers, or even JSON), but we're using XML right now and this little hickup doesn't merit changing everything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have something I think I can use - I'll add an XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="") to the Bar partial class in a seperate cs module.